# how to access control properties?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have some text boxes. I am applying MVVM model and one textbox has keypress event. Not able to access textbox properties and label properties inside MVVM model. how to access them? Can i call them inside calculation when i keypress divide_txt_KeyDown? Assume that these textboxes are inside dataTemplate.

```
<TextBox x:Name="a1" Width="96" Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="20"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="a2" Width="96" Canvas.Top="300" Canvas.Left="144"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="add_txt" Width="96" Canvas.Top="344" Canvas.Left="20"/>        
        <TextBox x:Name="multiple_txt" Width="96" Canvas.Top="344" Canvas.Left="144"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="divide_txt" Width="96" Canvas.Top="344" Canvas.Left="264"  KeyDown="divide_txt_KeyDown" />
```

---

```
 public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemViewModel()
    {

    }

    private void divide_txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        calculation();
    }

public void calculation() {

    }

    private void divide_txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        add_txt.Text = a1.Text + a2.Text;
        double v1 = Convert.ToDouble(a1.Text);
        double v2 = Convert.ToDouble(a2.Text);
        add_txt.Text = (v1 + v2).ToString();
        multiple_lbl.Content = (v1 * v2).ToString();
        divide_txt.Text = (v1 / v2).ToString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to access control properties in your view model you have completely misunderstood what the MVVM design pattern is all about. Then you might as well get rid of your `ItemViewModel` class and put all code in the code-behind of the view.

The view model should not have any knowledge about the control. What you should do is to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBoxes` in the view to `string` properties in the view model and set these source properties in the view model class:

```
<TextBox Binding="{Binding A1}" />
<TextBox Binding="{Binding A2}" />
<TextBox Binding="{Binding Add}" />
```

Make sure that the view model class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

The `KeyDown` event should be handled using a command. Please refer to the following link for more information about this.

**Handling events in an MVVM WPF application:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

Comment: Assume that these textboxes are inside datatemplate. i am binding them with combobox. So using INotifyPropertyChanged for this and implemented mvvm model for this.

Comment: Is that a question? The answer is the same.

Comment: combobox definitely need inotifypropertychanged for my program. so textboxes are binded to selected value of combobox and added to listbox. then definitetly i need MVVM model know! and textboxes inside the model.

Comment: There is no ComboBox mentioned in your original question so I don't know what you are talking about. Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved and then ask another question if you have a new issue.

Comment: i didn't wanted to ask a big question. So simply i wrote, how to access controls inside my mvvm model.

Comment: And this question has already been answered: You *don't* access controls in a view model class. You should do some reading on MVVM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: <local:ViewModel1 x:Key="wbItem"/>
        <local1:ViewModel2 x:Key="ifItem"/>
        <local2:ViewModel3 x:Key="ofItem"/> Actually this worked for me like charm.